# How to match one Text with a whole column? Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So some agency want to know how many users are allowed to get into their system they send me all users that are allowed, now i want match every user with their data, if the user exit in their column then write "TRUE" if not "FALSE"? Thank you.[image]

| Names | Agency1 | Allowed? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user565 | user44 | FALSE |
| user4851 | ***user4*** | TRUE |
| user548 | user3 | FALSE |
| ***user4*** | user884 | FALSE |

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Your question may be closed, if it isn't self contained. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to do it or you just want the answer ? I believe if you put just a little effort you can find the answer on your own. Anyway, please show what you've tried and where you're stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(MATCH(B2:B5; A2:A5; ))>0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to accomplish this using [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378). Something like:

`MATCH(C2,B$2:B)`

*Note that I am using `B$2` here. This means that when you copy this formula to each row, it will continue to look at all of the values in xolumb `B`. So this is only the formula for the first row.*

If MATCH does not find the result, it will return `#N/A`. This can be handled with [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944):

`IFNA(MATCH(C2, B$2:B), FALSE)`

This will return FALSE if the MATCH returns `#N/A`

Now, to get your TRUE/FALSE value, you need to do a [comparison](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) of the above:

`IF(IFNA(MATCH(C2, B$2:B), FALSE), TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: I tried it but still not working

Comment: If you want help, you're going to have to provide more information. I created a sample sheet and it worked. What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use COUNTIF.

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(A2:A5,B2:B5)>0)
```

[image]